# Where can I find my custom application page in central admin?

Tags: custom

I am using sharepoint 2010 and created in VS2010 a new application page by the template "Central Administration PAge (CKSDev)". It created automatic for me the page and also the action. See here the action:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <CustomAction Id="CentralAdminPage1"
                    GroupId="MyAdministrationPages"
                    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Applications"
                    Sequence="50"
                    Title="My Test Administration Page">
        <UrlAction Url="_admin/CustomSettings/CentralAdminPage1.aspx"/>
      </CustomAction>
    </Elements>
```

and group code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomActionGroup Id="MyAdministrationPages"
                     Title="My Administration Pages"
                     Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Applications"
                     ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/CentralAdmin_SystemSettings_FarmManagement_32x32.png"/>
</Elements>
```

I deploy it and go to central admin but cannot find it. Where can I find my custom application page in central admin?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the element files have been included in your feature in the package. Its easy to forget, also depending on your VS settings, new elements created get placed in random features